# What happens to a VAR when I standarize variables?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, standardization

Suppose you have 6 or 7-time series that are stationary.

But my question is what does happen to a VAR when I standardize all the variables of the VAR

This makes that the mean is 0 and the standard deviation 1.

What implications does the VAR with standardized data have?